# How to manage borders of a sprite using SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite

I am just starting with `SpriteKit`, and I want to make a ball fall into a box...
I designed an open 2d square to act as a box.  Whenever I launch the project, the ball doesn't enter the box, it rolls to one side.  The background for my box is transparent.
If I haven't explained it well enough, I would basically like to know if I can make a `sprite` (ball) enter my other `sprite` (box), from one angle, but not be able to get into the box from a side angle...

Comment: You can definitely do this.  You can either make the box using three thin rectangles as each side, or you can make a custom "box" physicsBody.  I recommend setting ShowPhysics = true; in the view controller so you can visually see your physicsBody, making it easier to tell how things should work.

Comment: @meisenman, thanks very much!  I will certainly give that a go!  Have a nice Christmas!